# Изменение прозрачности Grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid, прозрачность

Есть два `Grid` и `ComboBox`

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Button Width="180" Padding="5" FontSize="16" Content="Button1" IsDefault="True" />
</Grid>
```

```
<Grid Name="Grid2">
    <Button Width="180" Padding="5" FontSize="16" Content="Button2" />
</Grid>
```

```
<ComboBox Name="Change" FontSize="30" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Нужно, чтобы при изменении `Item` в `СomboBox` менялась прозрачность `Grid1` и `Grid2`.

При выборе первого `Item`, прозрачность `Grid1` = 1, `Grid2` = 0. При выборе второго `Item`, прозрачность `Grid2` = 1, `Grid1` = 0.

**Дополнительные вопросы:**

- Если в каждом `Grid` несколько `TextBox` и мне нужно, чтобы при выборе первого `Item` появлялся первый `TextBox` в первом `Grid` и второй `TextBox` во втором `Grid`, а при выборе второго Item, появлялся второй `TextBox` во втором `Grid` и второй `TextBox` во втором `Grid`. Когда появляется один, другой исчезает.
- Если объекты накладываются друг на друга, то нельзя будет нажать на `TextBox`, который расположен на заднем плане, так как его перекрывает другой `TextBox`, расположенный на переднем плане. Есть ли свойство, позволяющее на время отключить `TextBox`, как будто его и нет и включать это свойство, при изменении `ComboBox`?

Comment: Вам нужна не прозрачность, а Visibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в ваши гриды стиль с тригером, в котором будет происходить привязка к 
свойству `SelectedIndex` элемента `ComboBox`:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Button Width="180" Padding="5" FontSize="16" Content="Button1" IsDefault="True" />
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Change, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>

<Grid Name="Grid2">
    <Button Width="180" Padding="5" FontSize="16" Content="Button2" />
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Change, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>


<ComboBox Name="Change" FontSize="30" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Задал дополнительные вопросы

Comment: @A.Hall: Нехорошо изменять смысл вопроса после того, как уже был дан ответ. Дополнительные вопросы задавайте отдельными вопросами.

Comment: @A.Hall 1) Делаете по аналогии с гридами: добавляете стиль для `TextBox` и биндите к выбранному `ComboBoxItem`.  2) Используйте свойство `Visibility` вместо `Opacity`.